# Rotate Mapbox GL JS map after flyTo transition

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I can't seem to have much luck chaining a rotateTo transition after a flyTo transition, here are 2 examples the first one chains another flyTo transition after the 'moveend' event is fired, this works but if I try to rotate instead, no luck. Am I trying to do something silly?

[Fly after transition](http://jsbin.com/demecovehi/1/edit?html,console,output)

[Rotate after transition](http://jsbin.com/komaloceci/1/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 2):

I tried your [rotate after transition](http://jsbin.com/komaloceci/1/edit?html,console,output) example, and saw the same error you encountered (only `flyTo` operation works, `rotateTo` did not).

But when I swapped the operations (`map.rotateTo()` first, then `map.flyTo()`), then I was able to get both operations to work.

I see that [#2855](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2855) has been filed in [mapbox-gl-js](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js).

It may not fit into your workflow, but it appears that you can achieve both operations by swapping.  Then awaiting the response from Mapbox on Github issues.

---

This works

```
map.once('moveend', function(){
    console.log('moveend logging');
  map.flyTo({  center: [-74.50, 40]});
});

map.rotateTo(45.0, {duration:3000});
```

---

This did not

```
map.once('moveend', function(){
    console.log('moveend logging');
    map.rotateTo(45.0, {duration:3000});
});

map.flyTo({  center: [-74.50, 40]});
```

Comment: Looks like it was a bug and it got fixed https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2855 :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option to solve this will be using `map.easeTo(...)` to support both location change and rotation change without waiting for `moveend` using a single call.